# IllegalArgumentException at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.setOutputProperty

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jar, jdeveloper

I am using transformer to transform one type to another type. Code for this is

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer  = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");//Getting error here        
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileWriter(outputFilePath));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

The Stack trace of the exception is 
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.setOutputProperty(JXTransformer.java:798)

I am using Jdeveloper and its java version 1.6 added jars jdom1.0 and xercesimpl.jar

Will any one help on this.

Comment: Well, you are obviously passing a non allowed property. The javadoc says: _java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - If the property is not supported, and is not qualified with a namespace._

Comment: so,how to avoid this exception

Comment: without {http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount property the result getting generated with excess tags starting with XSLStylesheet..i want to avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the (rarely-used) Oracle XSLT engine (the one that Oracle developed before they acquired Sun and Java), but you are supplying an output property defined by Apache Xalan. Decide which XSLT engine you actually want to use, and then don't set properties that this engine doesn't recognize (or catch the exception).

Actually setOutputProperty() shouldn't really throw this exception when the property name is namespace-qualified, but the spec doesn't say this all that clearly, and in any case the spec has been considerably refined since the Oracle processor was last updated, so it's not totally unreasonable.

Comment: Can you say which jar files need to use with java 1.6 to avoid this issue

Comment: Preferably, get the Oracle XDK off your classpath. If you can't do that, use one of the various JAXP mechanisms to control which TransformerFactory you instantiate, e.g. setting the system property javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory to the XSLT engine you want, e.g. Apache Xalan or Saxon. Can't be more specific because I don't know JDeveloper.

Comment: I set the System property and its working fine. thanks